# How to redirect to a specific page on any error in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, error

I have a live running e-commerce platform, when there is any kind of error, it displays **error number** with text saying "**There has been an error processing your request**".

How to avoid this page and show a normal page with default Magento header and footer and a custom content saying something like "Something went wrong, please try again"

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with the [.htaccess ErrorDocument directive](https://www.addedbytes.com/blog/error-documents-for-beginners).  If you search for "ErrorDocument", you should find the following couple of lines in your .htaccess file:

```
# For 404s and 403s that aren't handled by the application, show plain 404 response
ErrorDocument 404 /pub/errors/404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /pub/errors/404.php
```

You can simply append a few lines for the 500-505 errors that you are experiencing:

```
# for Internal Server Error
ErrorDocument 500 /pub/errors/404.php 
# for Service Unavailable
ErrorDocument 503 /pub/errors/404.php
# for Gateway Timeout
ErrorDocument 504 /pub/errors/404.php
```

**Note:**
The three errors that I included are for specific errors and should include yours, but if that is not the case, the link at the top of this post has a full breakdown of the potential HTTP response codes that you could add.